# How to separate character from stdout into variables

Tags: ansible

I have the following output in stdout of register output:

> “server1,Running\nserver2,Running\nserver3,Not Activated\nserver4,Not Activated”

I want to create a list of just the Not Activated server:

```yaml
vmoff:
  - name: server3
  - name: server4
```

Also I have following output in stdout:

> “server1,0.5\nserver2,0.7\nserver3,1.0\nserver4,0.5\n”

I want to turn into the following:

```yaml
vmlist:
  - name: server1
    proc: 0.5
  - name: server2
    proc: 0.7
  - name: server3
    proc: 1.0
  - name: server4
    proc: 0.5
```

Comment: To start with, don't use `stdout`, use `stdout_lines`, which would be a list already.

Comment: You should also provide your version of Ansible as 2.11 introduce a `split` Jinja filter that can help you with the requirement at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the registered stdout

```yaml
reg:
  stdout: server1,Running\nserver2,Running\nserver3,Not Activated\nserver4,Not Activated
```

Create a dictionary

```yaml
vm_all: "{{ dict(reg.stdout|
                 split('\\n')|
                 select()|
                 map('split', ',')|
                 list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
vm_all:
  server1: Running
  server2: Running
  server3: Not Activated
  server4: Not Activated
```

Now, select the not activated servers and map the attribute name

```yaml
vm_not_activated: "{{ vm_all|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='status')|
                      selectattr('status', 'eq', 'Not Activated')|
                      map(attribute='name')|
                      list }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
vm_not_activated:
  - server3
  - server4
```

If you need the dictionaries, add the filter *community.general.dict_kv* to the pipe

```yaml
vm_not_activated: "{{ vm_all|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='status')|
                      selectattr('status', 'eq', 'Not Activated')|
                      map(attribute='name')|
                      map('community.general.dict_kv', 'name')|
                      list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
vm_not_activated:
  - name: server3
  - name: server4
```

---

Similarly, given the registered stdout

```yaml
reg:
  stdout: server1,0.5\nserver2,0.7\nserver3,1.0\nserver4,0.5\n
```

Create a dictionary

```yaml
vmdict: "{{ dict(reg.stdout|
                 split('\\n')|
                 select()|
                 map('split', ',')|
                 list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
vmdict:
  server1: '0.5'
  server2: '0.7'
  server3: '1.0'
  server4: '0.5'
```

Now, create the list

```yaml
vmlist: "{{ vmdict|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='proc') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
vmlist:
  - name: server1
    proc: '0.5'
  - name: server2
    proc: '0.7'
  - name: server3
    proc: '1.0'
  - name: server4
    proc: '0.5'
```

Comment: Hi, i cant put that on my yml, here is the complete senario:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71759022/how-to-separate-the-output-of-register-into-dict