# How to separate the output of register into dict

Tags: ansible

I have the following output:

```
    TASK [debug] ***********************
    ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "NAME": "server1",
                    "SEC_SYS": "CONT2"
                },
                "rc": 0,
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "vm1,Not Activated\nvm2,Not Activated\nvm3,Running\nvm4,Running\nvm5,Not Activated\nvm6,Running\n",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "vm1,Not Activated",
                    "vm2,Not Activated",
                    "vm3,Running",
                    "vm4,Running",
                    "vm5,Not Activated",
                    "vm6,Running"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "NAME": "server2",
                    "SEC_SYS": "CONT1"
                },
                "rc": 0,
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "vm1,Running\nvm2,Running\nvm3,Not Activated\nvm4,Not Activated\nvm5,Running\nvm6,Not Activated\n",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "vm1,Running",
                    "vm2,Running",
                    "vm3,Not Activated",
                    "vm4,Not Activated",
                    "vm5,Running",
                    "vm6,Not Activated"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "failed": false,
                "item": {
                    "NAME": "server3",
                    "SEC_SYS": "CONT2"
                },
                "rc": 0,
                "stderr": "",
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "stdout": "vm1,Not Activated\nvm2,Not Activated\nvm3,Running\nvm4,Running\nvm5,Not Activated\nvm6,Running\n",
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "vm1,Not Activated",
                    "vm2,Not Activated",
                    "vm3,Running",
                    "vm4,Running",
                    "vm5,Not Activated",
                    "vm6,Running"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to turn into the following list:

```
vm_off:
   - SEC_SYS: CONT2
     VM_NA: 
       - vm1
       - vm2
       - vm5
  - SEC_SYS: CONT1
     VM_NA: 
       - vm3
       - vm4
       - vm6
```

Then sum the proc of the Not Activated VM, comparing from the list:

```
vmlist: 
  - name: vm1
    proc: 0.5
  - name: vm2
    proc: 0.7
  - name: vm3
    proc: 1.0
  - name: vm4
    proc: 0.5
  - name: vm5
    proc: 0.5
  - name: vm6
    proc: 0.5
```

The expected output will be:

```
proc_steal:
     - server: CONT1
       proc: 1.7
     - server: CONT2
       proc: 2.0
```

I cant separate the stdout_lines into a dict because it appear an error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'results'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/val.yml': line 17, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - set_fact:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

My .yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    vmservers:
      - NAME: server1
        SEC_SYS: CONT2
      - NAME: server2
        SEC_SYS: CONT1
      - NAME: server3
        SEC_SYS: CONT2
  tasks:
    - name: get not activated vm
      ansible.builtin.script: "vm.sh {{ item.SEC_SYS }}"
      register: output
      loop: "{{ vmservers }}"
 
    - set_fact:
        vm_all: "{{ vm_all | default([]) + [item.results.stdout_lines.split(',')] }}"
      with_items: "{{ output }}"

    - debug:
        var: output
   
    - debug:
        var: vm_all
```

the vm.sh just take a list of vm and its state:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "CONT1" ]; then
  case $1 in
    "CONT1") cat cont1.txt;;
  esac
else
  case $1 in
    "CONT2") cat cont2.txt;;
  esac
fi
```

root:ansible# cat cont1.txt

vm1,Running

vm2,Running

vm3,Not Activated

vm4,Not Activated

vm5,Running

vm6,Not Activated

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71759022/edit) and fix the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the dict vmoff2 using the following:

```
   - name: create Not Activated VM list
      set_fact:
        vmoff: >-
          {{ vmoff | default([])
          + [{
              'sec_sys': item.item.SEC_SYS,
              'vm_na': dict(item.stdout_lines
                | from_yaml
                | select()
                | map('split', ',')
                | list)
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ output.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.SEC_SYS }}"
```

And eliminate the duplicate output with:

```
    - name: eliminate duplicate
      set_fact:
        vmoff2: "{{ vmoff2 | default([]) + [{'sec_sys': item.1.0.sec_sys, 'vm_na': item.1.0.vm_na }] }}"
      loop: "{{ vmoff|groupby('sec_sys') }}"
```

Finally i have the following dict:

```
    "vmoff2": [
        {
            "sec_sys": "CONT1",
            "vm_na": {
                "vm1": "Running",
                "vm2": "Running",
                "vm3": "Not Activated",
                "vm4": "Not Activated",
                "vm5": "Running",
                "vm6": "Not Activated"
            }
        },
        {
            "sec_sys": "CONT2",
            "vm_na": {
                "vm1": "Not Activated",
                "vm2": "Not Activated",
                "vm3": "Running",
                "vm4": "Running",
                "vm5": "Not Activated",
                "vm6": "Running"
            }
        }
    ]
---------------
    "vmprof2": [
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "0.5",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.5",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.5"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": {
                "vm1": "1.0",
                "vm2": "0.7",
                "vm3": "1.0",
                "vm4": "0.7",
                "vm5": "0.5",
                "vm6": "0.7"
            },
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
```

I want to sum the proc of the Not activated VM, and have the following output:

```
proc_steal:
     - server: CONT1
       proc: 1.7
     - server: CONT2
       proc: 2.4
```

I tried the following:

```
  - name: create proc_steal list
      set_fact:
        proc_steal: >-
          {{ proc_steal | default([])
          + [{
              'sec_sys': item.sec_sys,
              'proc': vmprof2
                | selectattr('sec_sys', '==', item.sec_sys)
                | selectattr('proc', '==', item.vm_na)
                | sum(attribute='value')
                | float
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ vmoff2 }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.sec_sys }}"
```

but i get:

```
    "proc_steal": [
        {
            "proc": 0.0,
            "sec_sys": "CONT1"
        },
        {
            "proc": 0.0,
            "sec_sys": "CONT2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is not making the sum, maybe because is not float, but when i tried to put float i have an error, any guess?